# How to Connect to MS SQL Server in Objective-C/Cocoa on Mac?

Tags: sql-server, objective-c, database, cocoa, macos

I need to write a Mac Objective-C/Cocoa app that connects to a remote MS SQL Server. How to do it?

Also, how to run SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE in this connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quick Googling reveals the [MacSQL Framework](http://www.rtlabs.com/fwork/), which claims to support SQL Server.

Comment: The top link on "Some Quick Googling" is now this page;  And your link is now broken.

This is why SO frowns on posting links.